# How to Keep Rig Always In Front in Blender 2.8+?

Tags: animation, rigging

Ever Since Blender 2.8 whenever I proxy an Armature I have to Manually set it In Front in the Viewport Display Options. I was hoping if there was a way to permanently do that in the File before Proxy ?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by permanently doing that in the proxy?
I would say select the armature and then in the inspector you go to the bones and go to visibility or something like that and then click always in front.
feel free to comment below

Comment: Let me explain - I normally Link my files and proxy them. So they basically have a Master File where I link them from. For most settings - Whatever is set in the Master File will carry over once its linked. So incase of any issue I can just edit the master file and it updates in the Shot. In this instance, even if I have set the armature 'In front' in the Master File it just defaults to Off once i Link and Proxy the Armature. Thats fine for one character but doing that for every character everytime is just tedious so I was wondering if there was a setting to do that